# Defining $dy=f'(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

In integration,we often use $u$ substitution method which says if $u=f(x)$ then $du=f'(x)dx$. Here $dx, du$ are infinitesimals. But $dx,du$ aren't real numbers, then how can we multiply them? Is this independently derived from non standard analysis?

Also is a constant multiplied by an infinitesimal also an infinitesimal?

Comment: Since dx is an independent variable,suppose dx is a large number.Then du is also another large number.Then we get $\int f(u)du$.But from riemannean sums of integral,we know $du$ has to be infinitely many small for the rectangles to actually equal the curves area.But in this case differential du is quite large and is also a fixed number so we can't let $du$ approach 0 for the riemann sum.Sorry if I am being foolish.By rieman sum,I mean the normal sum by how we approximate arra and make it precise by taking limit of the sum as $dx$ approaches $0$.

Comment: But we are taught $\int$ is just the limit of a sum.I mean by $\int f(u)du$ we are actually finding out the area of the graph $f(u)$.Am I wrong?Because this is written in all the books while beginning integration.

Comment: I don't understand,could you please explain in detals?As far as I know integration is basically finding out the area under a graph.

Comment: I don't understand,my question was regarding change of variables method involving dx,dy which were supposed to be infinitesimals.But you refuted that they were differentials.How can there not be any direct connection of differentials with integration?

Answer (score 1):

Actually setting $u = f(x)$ and $du = f'(x) dx$ is just a mnemonic, a notation trick. The actual theorem is

$$\int_a^b g(f(x))f'(x)\,dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}g(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Where can I find the proof of the theorem?

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution